# htaccess subdomain redirect changes address

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I've been reading post on SO for two days now and have tried dozen samples but can't get my rewrites to work.

Here's my situation:
I'm running Apache on Ubuntu.
I have 2 files in my root (file1.php, file2.php) and a folder (website)
I want to redirect www.mydomain.com and domain.com to the folder. That part is working with this set of rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ website/ [L]
```

Now I'm trying to use subdomains.
demo.mydomain.com should go to www.mydomain.com/file1.php?v=demo
demo.mydomain.com/file2.php should go to www.mydomain.com/file2.php?v=demo
AND the url in the address bar of the browser should not change.

I already have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?v=%1 [L]
##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file1.php?v=%1 [L]
```

This results in demo.mydomain.com/file2.php going to www.mydomain.com/file2.php?v=demo, that is OK but the URL also changes in the address bar. That is not OK.
demo.mydomain.com redirects to www.mydomain.com which goes to the website folder, this is totally wrong.

As you can see, I'm nearly there. I'm just missing some small pieces.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a different domain in your rewrite rule as you current domain (demo.mydomain.com vs. www.mydomain.com). Apache doesn't know these point to the same server and document_root, so apache does a redirect. Just remove the domain name part.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   $1?v=%1 [L,QSA]
##
...
```